# Acceder, leer y escribir archivos c++

Tags: java, c++, poo

Estuve trabajando java y utilicé Scanner para acceder al contenido de archivos de texto, y también Printstream para escribir en nuevos archivos, ¿cuales serían la manera análoga de realizar estas acciones en c++?
por ejemplo, en java:

```
public Class(Scanner sc) {
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
            sc.nextLine();
        ........

public void write(PrintStream out) {
        out.println("texto....");
        ......
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ dispone de los flujos de datos (stream) a archivos.

Así pues, para leer un archivo línea a línea:

```
if (std::ifstream archivo{"archivo.txt"})
{
    std::string linea{};
    while (std::getline(archivo, linea))
    {
        // 'linea' contiene la linea leida
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo\n";
}
```

Y para escribir:

```
if (std::ofstream archivo{"archivo.txt"})
{
    archivo << "Información\n"; // Escribimos en el archivo.
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo\n";
}
```